# How to have information that a touch event has happened and what kind of touch event and not handle it?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, nsnotificationcenter, uitouch, uievent

i want to create an NSNotification for all the the touch events happening with there specific recognise types and not handling them just observing them, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate reference, it could work for you:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate will work for you. You can selectively enable touch events through the mrthod.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return (touch.view != self.itemWhichDoNotRequireTouch);
}
```

Comment: sir, touch.view is a readonly property also my question was not to interfere in responder chain of UIGestureRecogniser i don't want view not to handle a gesture but only that whenever there is a gesture i get a notification that a certain gesture event has happened.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS 6 Cookbook has an example of subclassing the UIWindow, and sending the events to a singleton UIView that's sat above the UIWindow.  Works really well.

https://github.com/erica/iOS-6-Cookbook/tree/master/C01%20Gestures/13%20-%20TOUCHkit

Edit: this is also observational, it does not interrupt the responder chain.